# Can statement-level triggers lead to mutating-tables

Tags: oracle, triggers, mutating-table

Or only row-level triggers are said to cause such mutations?

I rephrase my question:

Which trigger types will be impacted by constraining factors brought on by mutating tables?

Comment: Why don't you try and check what happens?

Comment: +1johnbk for asking pop to try(pop without finding this by yourself you will not learn ) these guys wants you to find the answer by yourself and if you dint get the answer then'l ask ,they will definitely help you  ,if you know that row level trigger gives you mutating error then what harm in removing that `for each row` clause from that trigger and them try to insert :)

Comment: I rephrase my question: Which trigger types will be impacted by constraining factors brought on by mutating tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both can lead to mutating tables. It is a matter of what you reference in the trigger. Like the folks here have already said, try it and find out if works.

Answer (score 1):

No.

To quote from [Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:9579487119866#64927037142680): "Only row triggers are subject to mutating table constraints, STATEMENT triggers (before/after) are not."